# Mac Speech 'choppy'

Tags: macos, speech

Is there any reason why the text to speech reader will sound choppy?

On the first attempt to read a block of text, it stops for a split second every few clauses - even failing to say some words along the process. On the second pass, it does a lot better.

It feels like it's buffering. It wasn't like this before.

Some points:

- Apparently, it's not related to software since I've observed it in Snow Leopard, and it's there after upgrading to Yosemite.
- Changing the voice and voice speed does not help.
- Restarting doesn't help either, initially I thought a high-demand process was taking up CPU time that prevents this function from working effectively.

MacBook Pro Late 2011 on Yosemite.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: In Activity Monitor, how is you CPU and your RAM doing?

Answer (score 1):

Buscar is thinking exactly what I was. Open activity monitor and keep an eye on processor and RAM usage when your Mac is reading some text to you.

It is likely that **some** resource is limited and slowing things down. It is most likely RAM or CPU but it is also possible that the Mac is doing a lot of reading/writing to the HD or even the network or other mounted device.

If you reboot the Mac, make sure that there are no mounted network volumes nor any removable media (CDs, USB flash drives, etc.) mounted and then try to have some text spoken with nothing else running does the same thing happen?

If so try it with your network turned off, maybe even in Safe Mode.